# How to determine whether a file is duplicated but has a different name?

Tags: files, filenames, file-search

Say you have one file called `foo.pdf`. How can I find out whether my machine contains another file, say `bar.pdf`, that has the exact same content but just a different name?

Comment: I would say just `md5sum` each file, the output should be the same.

Comment: @guillermochamorro I meant how can I search for this file. I don't know whether `bar.pdf` exists.

Comment: Do you mean same file size, byte-by-byte comparison, checksums or same content like after converting PDF to PDF?

Answer (score 2):

Tell me if this does work (won't be fast):

```
find /home/user -type f -name "*.pdf" -exec md5sum {} + 2> /dev/null | uniq -f2 -D
```

Comment: guillermo chamorro You beat me to the answer. I was going to suggest the same thing. :D

Comment: Shouldn't it be `… | sort | uniq -w32 -D` to print the lines with the same hash?

Answer (score 1):

`fdupes` sounds quite smart, but it does match all the files together. You could use a couple of the same techniques more optimally if you already have a single file that you want to match.

You could start by getting the file size of `foo.pdf`, and constructing a `find` command that matches the exact size only. That should be a cheap shortlist.

Then you could cut the first few bytes (a few hundred) from each of those files, and compare those bytes with `cmp -s`. That should eliminate some more.

For files that are still possible duplicates, you can `cksum` or `md5sum` them.

You probably want to check the inode numbers are different from your original, in case you find a hard-linked copy.

Comment: Instead of the first few bytes (which may be the same in many files because of boilerplate headers), start comparing from the _middle_ of the file ;-)

Comment: Also, you should compare the device:inode tuples, not just the inode numbers.

Comment: My bad: the inode numbers are only unique within a given file system (partition, which looks like a device). Although, I'm suggesting using inode to detect hard links, and IIRC hard links are not supported cross-device anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `fdupes` to search for duplicate files in different directories. The default is to list duplicate files as blocks separated by a blank line.

If both files are in one directory `dir1`:

```
fdupes dir1
```

For a recursive search, add the `-r` / `--recurse` option:

```
fdupes -r dir1
```

You can search multiple directories and set the recurse option for specific dirs:

```
fdupes dir1 dir2 --recurse: dir3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rmlint -r
```

[rmlint](https://github.com/sahib/rmlint) is an extremely fast tool to find duplicates and optionally remove them if you want.

### Features

#### Finds…

- …Duplicate Files and duplicate directories.
- …Nonstripped binaries (i.e. binaries with debug symbols)
- …Broken symbolic links.
- …Empty files and directories.
- …Files with broken user or/and group ID.

#### Differences to other duplicate finders:

- Extremely fast (no exaggeration, we promise!)
- Paranoia mode for those who do not trust hashsums.
- Many output formats.
- No interactivity.
- Search for files only newer than a certain mtime.
- Many ways to handle duplicates.
- Caching and replaying.
- btrfs support.

This [tutorial](https://rmlint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) will help and guide you gently ;)